# Hamiltonian Prove.

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a graph of order $n$ with $e(G)>{n\choose2}-(n-2)$. Prove that $G$ is Hamiltonian.

On my way use induction, the basis step is clear.

But induction step assume that $G_1=G+x$ for all $x\notin V(G)$ with $e(G_1)>{n+1\choose2}-(n+1-2)$,

For induction hypothesis when should i use it?

Remark $e(G)=|E(G)|$.

Comment: @bof $e(G)=|E(G)|$ in graph theory.

Comment: $e(G)$ denotes the size (number of edges) of a graph $G$ ***IN SOME TEXTBOOKS***, for example, in Douglas West's *Introduction to Graph Theory*. On the other hand Chartrand and Lesniak's *Graphs & Digraphs*, Third Edition, p. 1, says: "the cardinality of its edge set is the *size* of $G$ and is often denoted by $m(G)$ or $m$." You haven't told us what book you are using; you are addressing your question to unknown people who have not necessarily read the same graph theory book as you; so it would be a good idea to define any terms that aren't completely standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a graph of order $n\gt3$ and size $e(G)\gt\binom n2-n+2=\binom{n-1}2+1$.
By the inductive hypothesis, the proposition holds for all graphs of order less than $n$.

**Claim.** $G$ contains a vertex $x$ of degree $\deg(x)\gt\frac{n-1}2$.

**Proof.** Otherwise we would have
$$2e(G)=\sum_{x\in V(G)}\deg(x)\le\frac{n(n-1)}2=\binom n2$$
so that $e(G)\le\frac12\binom n2$, but this contradicts our hypothesis that
$e(G)\gt\binom n2-n+2\gt\frac12\binom n2$.

Choose a vertex $v\in V(G)$ of degree $d(x)=d\gt\frac{n-1}2$. Then $G-x$ is a graph of order $n-1$, and
$$e(G-x)=e(G)-d\gt\binom{n-1}2+1-d.$$

**Case 1.** $d\le n-2$.

Then $e(G-x)\gt\binom{n-1}2+1-(n-2)=\binom{n-1}2-(n-1)+2$. Therefore, by the inductive hypothesis, the graph $G-x$ has a Hamiltonion circuit $C$. Since $\deg(x)\gt\frac{n-1}2$, the vertex $x$ is joined to two consecutive vertices of $C$, so there is also a Hamiltonian cycle in $G$.

**Case 2.** $d=n-1$, *i.e.*, $x$ is joined to all other vertices of $G$.

If $G-x$ is a complete graph, then $G$ is a complete graph and there's nothing to prove. Otherwise, let $u,v$ be two nonadjacent vertices of $G-x$, and let $H=G-x+uv$, a graph of order $n-1$ and size $e(H)=e(G-x)+1\gt\binom{n-1}2+2-d=\binom{n-1}2-(n-1)+2$. By the inductiove hypothesis, the graph $H$ has a Hamiltonian circuit $C$. If $uv\in E(C)$ then $C-uv+ux+xv$ is a Hamiltonian circuit of $G$. If $uv\notin E(C)$, choose any edge $yz\in E(C)$; then $C-yz+yx+xz$ is a Hamiltonian circuit of $G$.

**Remark.** This is best possible; for each $n\ge2$ there is an obvious example of a
non-Hamiltonian graph with $n$ vertices and $\binom{n-1}2+1$ edges.